# Angular: no puedo obtener dato de array dentro de array en un modal

Tags: array, angular

Tengo una tabla en la que cargo datos que me llegan a través de una API. Hasta aquí todo bien. Algunos de ellos están en un array dentro de array, pero en la vista he podido acceder a estos elementos. El problema surge cuando quiero transferir estos datos a un modal. Si los datos vienen en un arreglo dentro de un arreglo en el modal no me los muestra en {{pais.currencies.name}}. Y si lo cambio a {{currencie.name}} tal como está en la vista da ese error:  Property 'currencie' does not exist on type 'ModelComponent'.

¿Cómo debería hacerlo?

**Datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**vista html**

```
    <tr *ngFor="let pais of paises">
         <td>{{ pais.region }}</td>
         <td> {{ pais.name }}</td>
         <td>{{ pais.capital }}</td>
         <div class="wrapper">
         <td *ngFor="let currencie of pais.currencies">{{ currencie.name }}</td>
       </div>
         <td><img (click)="openModal(pais)"></td>
       </tr>
```

**modal html**

```
<ul class="list-group text-dark mb-3">
                   <li class="list-group-item active">{{pais.name}}</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">{{pais.capital}}</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">{{pais.currencies.name}}</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">Población: {{pais.population}}</li>
                 </ul>
```

**Model.ts**

```
@Input() pais: Paises | any;
```

**View.ts**

```
paises: Paises[] = [];
 paisSeleccionado: Paises | any;

openModal(pais: Paises){
   this.paisSeleccionado = pais;
   this.modalService.openModal();

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> {{pais.currencies.name}}

Eso es un error porque `currencies` es un arreglo.

Prueba esto:

```
 <li class="list-group-item">
   <span *ngFor="let currency of pais.currencies">{{currency.name}}</span>
 </li>
```

Comment: Efectivamente era eso. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es porque al declararlo en la misma etiqueta aun no se ha creado.
Prueba con esto.

'
`<div class="wrapper" *ngFor="let currencie of pais.currencies"> < td > {{ currencie.name }}< /td> < /div>`

Comment: Probé lo que comentas pero salen los mismos errores :(

Comment: Me pasa solo en este caso en el que esta info está dentro de otro array, con capital, region, etc no me pasa, aparece bien tanto en la vista como en el modal, pero con currencies aparece en la vista pero NO en el modal.